# map RDD to PairRDD in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to map RDD to pairRDD in scala, so I could use reduceByKey later. Here is what I did:

userRecords is of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[UserElement]

I try to create a pairRDD from userRecords like below:

```
val userPairs: PairRDDFunctions[String, UserElement] = userRecords.map { t =>
  val nameKey: String = t.getName()
  (nameKey, t)
}
```

However, I got the error:

type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, com.mypackage.UserElement)] 
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[String,com.mypackage.UserElement]

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing the import to `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`. This brings all the right implicit conversions in scope to create the PairRDD.

The example below should work (assuming you have initialized a SparkContext under sc):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val f = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5))
val g: PairRDDFunctions[String, Int] = f.map( x => (x.toString, x))
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do that as it is done via [implicits](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$) (explicitly `rddToPairRDDFunctions`). Any RDD that is of type `Tuple2[K,V]` can automatically be used as a `PairRDDFunctions`. If you REALLY want to, you can explicitly do what the `implicit` does and wrap the RDD in a `PairRDDFunction`:

```
val pair = new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use keyBy method, you need to provide the key in the function,

in your example, you can simply give userRecords.keyBy(t => t.getName())

Comment: Example here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/How-to-create-spark-PairRDD-in-scala/td-p/30512